# WPF Binding and Custom ListView and ListViewItems

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I need a WPF control that functions similar to the 'Resolve Conflicts' window in TFS, and other similar source control systems.

I have the following classes

```
 public class Conflict:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private List<Resolution> _resolutions;
    private bool _focused;
    private bool _hasResolutions;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public List<Resolution> Resolutions
    {
        get { return _resolutions; }
        set
        {
            _resolutions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Resolutions");
        }
    }

    public bool Focused
    {
        get { return _focused; }
        set { 
            _focused = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Focused");
        }
    }

    public bool HasResolutions

    {
        get { return _resolutions.Any(); }
        set
        {
            _hasResolutions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HasResolutions");
        }
    }
}

public class Resolution
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Resolve()
    {
        //Logic goes here
    }
}
```

This almost identical to the functionality of the Team Foundation Server (TFS) 'Resolve Conflict' window shown below:

[image]

For each row in the image above, it is the same as my Conflcit object, and for each of the buttons, would be one of the Resolution objects on the Conflict object.

My plan was  to bind my List to a ListView, and then write a custom template or whatever to hide/show the buttons below it based on if it was selected or not.

To try to simplify what I need to accomplish, I have a List and I want to bind it to a control, and it look as close to the image above as possible.

How would I accomplish this and XAML and the code behind?

Comment: I have only tried to make a custom ItemTemplate, but I did not get very far. The issue I am having is I am not sure how to dynamically add buttons for each of the Resolution objects I have. Its almost like, I need a 'Repeater' for each of the Resolution objects on each of the conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can dynamically create a data template, and add buttons based on your `Conflict` objects:

```
    public DataTemplate BuildDataTemplate(Conflict conflict)
    {
        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();

        // Set a stackpanel to hold all the resolution buttons
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        template.VisualTree = factory;

        // Iterate through the resolution
        foreach (var resolution in conflict.Resolutions)
        {
            // Create a button
            FrameworkElementFactory childFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));

            // Bind it's content to the Name property of the resolution
            childFactory.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, new Binding("Name"));
            // Bind it's resolve method with the button's click event
            childFactory.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new Action(() => resolution.Resolve());

            // Append button to stackpanel
            factory.AppendChild(childFactory);
        }

        return template;
    }
```

You can do this in many different ways and this is just one of them.
I haven't test it, but this should be enough to get you started :)

Good luck

Comment: How am I setting this? Is this set on the ListView? This seems like what I need, but I am trying to test it, and not sure how to set it so I can test it.

Comment: I got it working, but the one thing that is weird is, the SetBinding(..) call is binding to the conflict name, and not the resolution name, so I am using SetValue and just passing in the name of the resolution.

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum The `SetBinding()` works exactly like the binding mechanism via xaml, and works accordingly to it's current dataContext. So, in order to make the binding of `Name` display the name of the resolution, you need to bind your `Resolutions` collection to some ItemsControls like a `ListBox\DataGrid` or `ItemsControl` itself, and apply this `DataTemplate` to it.